# CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS encoding

Tags: php, encoding, curl

I'm not sure about what encoding to use when using cURL:

> GET:
>
> (URL=) http://www.example.com/form.php?test=test+1
>
> (URL=)
> http://www.example.com/form.php?test=test%201

> POST:
>
> (POSTFIELDS=) test=test 1
>
> (POSTFIELDS=) test=test+1
>
> (POSTFIELDS=) test=test%201

Answer (score 5):

CURL can accept an array of arguments for post, and it'll take care of the encoding for you:

```
$array = (
    'test' => 'test 1',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
```

However, as per the curl docs (http://php.net/curl_setopt, search for CURLOPT_POST_FIELDS), for PHP, the pairs should be in `urlencode()` format:

```
$post_args = urlencode('test=test 1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
```